# Visual Studio 2015 add specific file to Gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

I am trying to add a specific `config.json` file to my gitignore file, but for some reason I can't figure this out!

I have a config file which I do not want to be included in the repo on Git, which it currently is, I want to add it to the gitignore to prevent it being pushed to Git with the rest of my solution.

I have added the name both to a `.gitignore` in the folder itself as well as the `.gitignore` in the repository settings of VS15, copied below.

I have this path, the path to the file in both.

Am i missing something with the paths here?

```
# Config files
Tests/API/config.json // This is the folder path to the file within my solution
```

`Repository Settings/.gitignore`

```
# Object files
*.o
*.ko
*.obj
*.elf

# Visual Studio Project Items:
*.suo

# Config files
Tests/API/config.json

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch
*.pch

# Libraries
*.lib
*.a
*.la
*.lo

... etc
```

Comment: So, you have added it to the `.gitignore`. What happens next?

Comment: Pushed to Git but the file is still included

Comment: What is "included"?

Comment: `Tests/API/config.json`, the file I'm trying not to have included

Comment: What does "included" mean? `.gitignore` does not delete any files from anywhere.

Comment: It's pushed to Git

Comment: So, if you pushed it before - it will be.

Comment: So I'd have to start a new repo?

Comment: You did not explain what you want to achieve. Hence it's not possible to suggest you a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/1139762/2747593).

Answer (score -1):

1. You can go to Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.
2. you update the specific config file.
3. Go to Team Explorer. Click the changes button as given below:
   [image: Changes button in Team Explorer]
4. You will see your config file being listed from step 2.
5. Right Click the config file and choose ignore this local item, as given below:
   [image: Ignore this local item]
6. The file will get added to gitignore as given below:
   [image: Local item added to gitignore]
7. Now commit and push the changes

Comment: I am sorry. I did not fully go through the comments. I will take care in future. can I remove my answer ?